# signal handling strange behaviour

Tags: c++, signals

I am just experimenting on signal handling , so I wrote a program , to test SIGINT , but something strange happens !

my code is this :

```
void signalHandle(int);

int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, signalHandle);

    for (int i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
    {
        cout << i <<"\r";
    }

}

void signalHandle(int signalValue)
{
    cout << "Interrupt signal (" << signalValue <<
        ") recieved . Do you wish to continue?" << endl;

    int response;

    cin >> response;

    if (response == 0)
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

    signal(SIGINT, signalHandle);
}
```

when I use ctrl+c , the program actually goes to the signalHandle function , but only print the message , and skip the rest . it is strange . I used an empty loop and It worked just fine . also , I used raise function , and it was fine too . I can't figure out why I get this strange result ... 
and i am a bit confused with this topic , most of the trainings just emphasize on raise function . i am working with windows , so where i must look for a deeper understanding ? my book wants me to look at the system manual ...

Comment: The [documentation for Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdkz3x12.aspx) says "SIGINT is not supported for any Win32 application. When a CTRL+C interrupt occurs, Win32 operating systems generate a new thread to specifically handle that interrupt".

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is related to the fact that you are using `cin` with an `int`, but supplying it with a 'char` at the same time.

So if you'll answer the question with anything other than `0`, the program will continue until the loops ends. But if you supply it with something that cannot be parsed to an `int`, like `y`, the `response` will be equal 0 and you program will `exit()`.

To fix this, you simply change `int reponse` to `char response` if that's what you want.

Comment: still acts same as before

Comment: What is the exact problem you are having?

Comment: the exact problem is this : there is no cin at all ! i press ctrl+c , program call the handler function , handler function print , it's first line message . then it seems function ignore the rest of codes , and simply , the for loop , continue to execute !

Comment: What are you typing as the answer to the question?

Comment: Nothing ! Just it skips it ! There seem to be no cin at all